# function is not defined, but is shown in page source

Tags: javascript, ajax

I've got a function that is called when a user clicks a button. Firebug keeps telling me that the function is not defined, but the code is in the header:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="Wildberry,Incense,Coconut,100Pcs" />
    <meta name="description" content="A true coconut fragrance.It's part of our 'Fruits' Fragrance Family." />
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <title>The Realms of Wickedry &bull; Wildberry Incense Coconut 100Pcs</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/shadowbox.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/shadowbox.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    Shadowbox.init({
        handleOversize: "drag",
        modal: true
    });

    var ajaxRequest;
    var url = "ajax.php";

    try{
        // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
        ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e){
        // Internet Explorer Browsers
        try{
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try{
                ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e){
                // Something went wrong
                alert("Your browser broke!");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    function cartRemove(id)
    {
        ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
            if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4 && ajaxRequest.status == 200){
                document.getElementById('cart').innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
            }
        }
        var params = "mode=cartremove&id=" + id;
        ajaxRequest.open("POST", url, true);
        ajaxRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        ajaxRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
        ajaxRequest.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
        ajaxRequest.send(params);
    }

    function wishRemove(id)
    {
        ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
            if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4 && ajaxRequest.status == 200){
                document.getElementById('wishlist').innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
            }
        }
        var params = "mode=wishremove&id=" + id;
        ajaxRequest.open("POST", url, true);
        ajaxRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        ajaxRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
        ajaxRequest.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
        ajaxRequest.send(params);
    }

    function addReview(id)
    {
        var u = 2;
        var review = document.review.reviewContent.value;
        ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
            if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4 && ajaxRequest.status == 200)
            {
                document.getElementById('reviews_div').innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
            }
        }
        var params = "mode=reviews&id=" + id + "&u=" + u + "&reviewContent=" + review;
        ajaxRequest.open("POST", url, true);
        ajaxRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        ajaxRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
        ajaxRequest.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
        ajaxRequest.send(params);
    }

    function wishAdd(id)
    {
        ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
            if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4 && ajaxRequest.status == 200){
                document.getElementById('wishlist').innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
            }
        }
        var params = "mode=wishlist&id=" + id;
        ajaxRequest.open("POST", url, true);
        ajaxRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        ajaxRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
        ajaxRequest.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
        ajaxRequest.send(params);
    }

    function shareWish()
    {
        window.open("./../shop/pages/share_pop.php","Share Wishlist","menubar=0,resizable=0,location=0,width=550,height=300");
    }

    function checkList()
    {
        var email_list = document.getElementById['email_list'].innerHTML;
        if(email_list == '')
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            var urlStr = '';
            var emails = email_list.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
            emails = emails.split(",");
            var count = emails.length;
            var i = 0;
            while(i <= count)
            {
                urlStr += "&email"+i+"="+emails[i];
            }

            ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function()
            {
                if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4 && ajaxRequest.status == 200){
                    document.getElementById('share_results').innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
                }
            }

            var params = "mode=share_wish"+urlStr;
            ajaxRequest.open("POST", url, true);
            ajaxRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            ajaxRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
            ajaxRequest.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
            ajaxRequest.send(params);
        }
    }
    </script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="maincontainer">
    <div id="topsection">
        <div class="innertube">
            <div id="header_img">
                <a style="border:none!important;" href="./../shop/index.php"><img style="border:none!important;" src="http://xxxxxxxxxxxx/shop/images/Wickedry.png" alt="header_img" /></a>

            </div>
            <div id="header_nav">
                <a class="nav_links" href="./../shop/index.php">Home</a>
                <a class="nav_links" href="./../shop/login.php?mode=logout&amp;sid=c02fc022a1553cc34964448194c9d20b">Logout [Chaos Creator]</a>

                                <a class="nav_links" href="./../shop/cart.php">View Cart</a>
                <a class="nav_links" href="./../shop/view.php?mode=wishlist">View Wishlist</a>
                            </div>

        </div>
    </div>  <div id="contentwrapper">
        <div id="contentcolumn">
            <div class="innertube">
                <div id="titleBar">
                    <div id="breadcrumb">
                        <a href="./../shop/view.php?mode=cat&id=15">Health & Beauty</a> &#62;&#62; <a href="./../shop/view.php?mode=subcat&id=67"> Candles</a>                  </div>

                    <div id="prod_title">
                        <h1>Wildberry Incense Coconut 100Pcs</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="prod_wrap">
                    <div id="prod_img">
                        <a class="prod_img_link" href="./images/products/large/GL5325.jpg" rel="shadowbox;title=Wildberry Incense Coconut 100Pcs;">
                            <img class="prod_img" src="http://xxxxxxxxx/shop/images/products/thumbs/GL5325.jpg" alt="Wildberry Incense Coconut 100Pcs" />

                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="prod_desc">
                        <p>A true coconut fragrance.It's part of our 'Fruits' Fragrance Family.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br />
                <div id="details">

                    <div id="prod_details">
                        Manufactured by: Wild Berry<br />
                        Model: GL5325<br />
                    </div>
                    <div id="prod_price">
                        $9.75                   </div>
                    <div id="quantity">

                                                    <form method="post" action="./../shop/view.php?mode=prod&amp;add_id=3806">
                                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="3806" />
                                <input type="text" name="quantity" value="0" onfocus="this.value='';" size="3" />
                                <input class="btn" type="submit" name="submit" value="Add to Cart" />
                            </form>
                                            </div>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                                        <a class="wish" href="#" onclick="wishAdd(3806);">Add to Wish List</a><br />

                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <strong>Add a Review:</strong><br />
                    <form action="" method="post" name="review">
                        <textarea cols="50" rows="10" name="reviewContent" id="reviewContent"></textarea><br />
                        <input type="submit" class="btn" name="review_submit" id="review_submit" onclick="addReview(3806);" value="Submit!" />
                    </form>
                    <br /><br /><div name="reviews_div"><p style="text-alignment:center;">There are no reviews for this item. Be the first to add one!</p></div>                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  <div id="leftcolumn">
        <div class="innertube">
            <div style="border: 1px solid white;">
                <div class="innertube">
                                <div id="search">
                <h2>Search</h2>

                <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="1" class="searchBox" width="100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center">
                            <form method="get" action="http://search.atomz.com/search/">
                                <table>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="center">
                                            <input type="hidden" name="sp_a" value="sp10049097" />
                                            <input size="25" name="sp_q" />

                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="center">
                                            <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn" />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                                <input type="hidden" name="sp_p" value="all">

                                <input type="hidden" name="sp_f" value="UTF-8">
                            </form>
                            <br />
                            <a href="./../shop/search.php">Advanced Search</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>              </div>

            </div>
            <div style="border: 1px solid white;margin-top: 10px;">
                <div class="innertube">
                                <div id="menu">
                <h2>Categories</h2>
                            </div>              </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  <div id="rightcolumn">
        <div class="innertube">
            <div style="border: 1px solid white;">
                <div class="innertube">
                                                    Welcome back, Chaos Creator!<br />
                <a href="<b>[phpBB Debug] PHP Notice</b>: in file <b>/shop/pages/blocks/login_box.php</b> on line <b>27</b>: <b>Undefined variable: u_profile</b><br />
">My Account</a><br />

                <a href="./../shop/cart.php">View Cart</a><br />
                <a href="./../shop/view.php?mode=wishlist">View Wishlist</a><br />
                                </div>
            </div>
            <div style="border: 1px solid white;margin-top: 10px;">
                <div class="innertube">
                        <h2>My Shopping Cart</h2>

    <div id="cart">
        You have no items in your cart! </div><br />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div style="border: 1px solid white;margin-top: 10px;">
                <div class="innertube">
                        <h2>My Wishlist</h2>
    <div id="wishlist">

        You have no items in your wishlist! </div>              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  <div id="footer">
        &copy; 2010-2011 by <a href="http://www.xxxxxxxx.com/">xxxxxxxxxxxxxx</a><br />
        Search Powered by <a href="http://www.sphider.eu/"><img src="http://xxxxxxxxxxxxx/shop/images/sphider-logo.png" border="0" style="vertical-align: middle" alt="Sphider"></a>

    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any idea what might be causing this?

UPDATED CODE using Caio's method:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="xxxxxxxxxxxxx" />
    <meta name="description" content="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <title>xxxxxxxxxxxxx &bull; xxxxxxxxxxxxxx</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/shadowbox.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/shadowbox.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    Shadowbox.init({
        handleOversize: "drag",
        modal: true
    });

    Element.prototype.postAjax = function (params, url)
    {
        var ajaxRequest;

        try {
            // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
            ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        catch (e) {
            // Internet Explorer Browsers
            try {
                ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject ("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e) {
                try {
                    ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject ("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                catch (e) {
                    // Something went wrong
                    alert("Your browser broke!");
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        ajaxRequest.open ("POST", url, true);

        ajaxRequest.setRequestHeader ("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        ajaxRequest.setRequestHeader ("Content-length", params.length);
        ajaxRequest.setRequestHeader ("Connection", "close");

        ajaxRequest.send (params);

        var _this = this;

        ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (ajaxRequest.readyState === 4) {
                if (ajaxRequest.status === 200) {
                    _this.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
                }
                else {
                    alert ("Error, please try again.");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    window.addEventListener ("load", function ()
    {
        var wishRemove = document.getElementById('wishRemove');
        var wishId = document.getElementById('wishId');
        var cartRemove = document.getElementById('cartRemove');
        var wishAdd = document.getElementById('wishAdd');
        var wishShare = document.getElementById('wishShare');
        var reviewAdd = document.getElementById('reviewAdd');
        var id = 1341;
        var wishList = document.getElementById("wishlist");
        var cartList = document.getElementById("cart");
        var reviewContent = document.getElementById("review_content");
        var reviewList = document.getElementById("reviews_div");

        if(cartRemove != undefined)
        {
            cartRemove.addEventListener("click", function () {
                cartList.postAjax("mode=cartRemove&id=" + id, "ajax.php");
            }, false);
        }

        if(wishRemove != undefined)
        {
            wishRemove.addEventListener("click", function () {
                wishList.postAjax("mode=wishRemove&id=" + wishId, "ajax.php");
            }, false);
        }

        if(reviewAdd != undefined)
        {
            reviewAdd.addEventListener("click", function () {
                reviewList.postAjax("mode=reviewAdd&id=" + id + "&reviewContent=" + review, "ajax.php");
            }, false);
        }

        if(wishAdd != undefined)
        {
            wishAdd.addEventListener("click", function () {
                wishList.postAjax ("mode=wishAdd&id=" + id, "ajax.php");
            }, false);
        }

        if(wishShare != undefined)
        {
            wishShare.addEventListener("click", function () {
                var email_list = document.getElementById['email_list'].innerHTML;
                if(email_list == '')
                {
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    var urlStr = '';
                    var emails = email_list.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
                    emails = emails.split(",");
                    var count = emails.length;
                    var i = 0;
                    while(i <= count)
                    {
                        urlStr += "&email"+i+"="+emails[i];
                    }
                    wishList.postAjax ("mode=wishShare&contacts=" + urlStr, "ajax.php");
                }
            }, false);
        }
    }, false);

    function shareWish()
    {
        window.open("./../shop/pages/share_pop.php","Share Wishlist","menubar=0,resizable=0,location=0,width=550,height=300");
    }
    </script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="maincontainer">
    <div id="topsection">
        <div class="innertube">
            <div id="header_img">
                <a style="border:none!important;" href="./../shop/index.php"><img style="border:none!important;" src="http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/shop/images/Wickedry.png" alt="header_img" /></a>

            </div>
            <div id="header_nav">
                <a class="nav_links" href="./../shop/index.php">Home</a>
                <a class="nav_links" href="./../shop/login.php?mode=logout&amp;sid=c02fc022a1553cc34964448194c9d20b">Logout [Chaos Creator]</a>

                                <a class="nav_links" href="./../shop/cart.php">View Cart</a>
                <a class="nav_links" href="./../shop/view.php?mode=wishlist">View Wishlist</a>
                            </div>

        </div>
    </div>  <div id="contentwrapper">
        <div id="contentcolumn">
            <div class="innertube">
                <div id="titleBar">
                    <div id="breadcrumb">
                        <a href="./../shop/view.php?mode=cat&id=19">xxxxxxxxxxx</a> &#62;&#62; <a href="./../shop/view.php?mode=subcat&id=230">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</a>                  </div>

                    <div id="prod_title">
                        <h1>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="prod_wrap">
                    <div id="prod_img">
                        <a class="prod_img_link" href="./images/products/large/DJ0279-02.gif" rel="shadowbox;title=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx;">
                            <img class="prod_img" src="http://xxxxxxxxx/shop/images/products/thumbs/DJ0279-02.gif" alt="xxxxxxxxxx" />

                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="prod_desc">
                        <p>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br />
                <div id="details">

                    <div id="prod_details">
                        Manufactured by: <br />
                        Model: DJ0279-02<br />
                    </div>
                    <div id="prod_price">
                        $8.18                   </div>
                    <div id="quantity">

                                                    <form method="post" action="./../shop/view.php?mode=prod&amp;add_id=1341">
                                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="1341" />
                                <input type="text" name="quantity" value="0" onfocus="this.value='';" size="3" />
                                <input class="btn" type="submit" name="submit" value="Add to Cart" />
                            </form>
                                            </div>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                                        <input type="button" class="btn" id="wishAdd" value="Add To WishList!" />

                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <strong>Add a Review:</strong><br />
                    <textarea cols="50" rows="10" id="review_content"></textarea><br />
                    <input type="submit" class="btn" id="reviewAdd" value="Add Review!" />
                    <br /><br /><div name="reviews_div"><p style="text-alignment:center;">There are no reviews for this item. Be the first to add one!</p></div>                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>  <div id="leftcolumn">
        <div class="innertube">
            <div style="border: 1px solid white;">
                <div class="innertube">
                                <div id="search">
                <h2>Search</h2>
                <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="1" class="searchBox" width="100%">

                    <tr>
                        <td align="center">
                            <form method="get" action="http://xxxxxxx/search/">
                                <table>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="center">
                                            <input type="hidden" name="sp_a" value="sp10049097" />
                                            <input size="25" name="sp_q" />
                                        </td>

                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="center">
                                            <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn" />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                                <input type="hidden" name="sp_p" value="all">
                                <input type="hidden" name="sp_f" value="UTF-8">

                            </form>
                            <br />
                            <a href="./../shop/search.php">Advanced Search</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>              </div>
            </div>

            <div style="border: 1px solid white;margin-top: 10px;">
                <div class="innertube">
                                <div id="menu">
                <h2>Categories</h2>
                ....
                <br />          </div>              </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  <div id="rightcolumn">
        <div class="innertube">
            <div style="border: 1px solid white;">
                <div class="innertube">
                                                    Welcome back, Chaos Creator!<br />
                <a href="./../shop/user.php">My Account</a><br />

                <a href="./../shop/cart.php">View Cart</a><br />
                <a href="./../shop/view.php?mode=wishlist">View Wishlist</a><br />
                                </div>
            </div>
            <div style="border: 1px solid white;margin-top: 10px;">
                <div class="innertube">
                        <h2>My Shopping Cart</h2>

    <div id="cart">
        <table><tr><td>     <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td rowspan="2" align="left">
                                    <a class="cart" href="#" onclick="cartRemove(13);">X</a>
                                </td>
                                <td align="right">
                                    <a class="cart" href="./../shop/view.php?mode=prod&amp;id=3806">Wildberry Incense Coconut 100Pcs</a>

                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    $9.75
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>

                </tr></table>   </div><br />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div style="border: 1px solid white;margin-top: 10px;">
                <div class="innertube">
                        <h2>My Wishlist</h2>
    <div id="wishlist">
        <table><tr><td align="center">      <a class="prod_img_link" href="./images/products/large/DJ0279-02.gif" rel="shadowbox;title=xxxxxxx;">

                                <img class="prod_img" src="http://xxxxxxxx/shop/images/products/thumbs/DJ0279-02.gif" alt="" />
                            </a><br />
                            <a class="wish" href="./../shop/view.php?mode=prod&amp;id=1341">xxxxxx</a><br />
                            $8.18<br />
                            <input type="hidden" id="wishId" value="11" />
                            <input type="button" class="btn" id="wishRemove" value="Remove" /></td></tr></table>    </div>              </div>
            </div>

            <div style="border: 1px solid white;margin-top: 10px;">
                <div class="innertube">
                                <div id="menu">
                <h2>Information</h2>
                <a href="./../shop/index.php?mode=shipping">Shipping &amp; Returns</a><br />
                <a href="./../shop/index.php?mode=conditions">Conditions</a><br />

                <a href="./../shop/index.php?mode=privacy">Privacy Notice</a><br />
                <a href="./../shop/index.php?mode=contact">Contact Us</a><br />
            </div>              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  <div id="footer">
        &copy; 2010-2011 by <a href="http://www.xxxxx.com/">xxxxxxx.com</a><br />

    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: which function is not defined?

Comment: Please post the HTML where the function is called and where this JS snippet is included

Comment: Why are you returning `false` after the `alert("Your browser broke!");`? You are not inside a function here, or are you?

Comment: This might be caused by syntax error in the function. If you can, use Firebug or something similar to see what happens.

Comment: Darin has a good point. wishAdd would not be defined if the browser fails on the invalid "return false" outside a function. Run the code in firefox and look in the error console to see "Return is outside of function"

Comment: @Darin @mplunjan The assumption that `wishAdd` would not be defined is wrong. It is a function declaration, therefore it is parsed/created before the actual code is run. The `SyntaxError: Illegial return statement` does not affect `wishAdd` in any way.

Comment: @Ivo Wetzel, I didn't say that the return statement would somehow affect or solve the problem. I just wanted to point this out in the hope that the OP would show his code because his question currently is not answerable.

Comment: @thinkdevcode it's the wishAdd() function that doesn't seem to be defined.

Comment: @Darin I'm adapting the code from another website, and i probably need to changed the alert(), return false lines to return an error code somehow, but i'm not sure how to implement that.

Comment: @alxx That's what I was thinking because I googled the issue last night and a lot of the fixes seemed to include fixing a syntax error somewhere. But i'll be a monkey's uncle if i can spot the darn thing.

Comment: @mplungjan The error console gives me the same thing as firebug: `wishAdd is not defined`

Comment: Ivo: This code ONLY displays the error about return false, so it was not a wild guess: `try { alert(a);} catch(e) {alert('nope');  return false; /* return outside function*/};function x() {alert(x);};x();`

Comment: Jason, please comment out the return false from the code above as instructed.

Comment: @Jason I strongly recommend using jQuery, it will most probably solve all problems and is much much easier to use.

Comment: @mplungian Removing the `return false;` seems to have done the trick. I have a question on using return and return false to break out of a function, though. I want to stop a function from executing and do nothing except pop up an alert if a variable has a certain value. `Return;` after the alert causes no alert to be issued. `Return false;` causes the alert to pop up but still executes the script in the else portion of the statement; same with just using the alert with no return afterwards. How can I effectively end the function's execution after the alert?

Comment: <img class="prod_img" src="http://xxxxxxxx/shop/images/products/thumbs/DJ0279-02.gif" alt="Raging Hard-Ons 7 inch Ballsy dildo" /> o_o

Comment: Ooops. Completely missed that one when posting. Now edited.

Answer (score 0):

Made some modifications, nothing is wrong, hope this helps.

[image]

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            Element.prototype.postAjax = function (params, url) {
                var ajaxRequest;

                try {
                    // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
                    ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
                }
                catch (e) {
                    // Internet Explorer Browsers
                    try {
                        ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject ("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                    } catch (e) {
                        try {
                            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject ("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                        }
                        catch (e) {
                            // Something went wrong
                            alert("Your browser broke!");
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                }

                ajaxRequest.open ("POST", url, true);

                ajaxRequest.setRequestHeader ("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                ajaxRequest.setRequestHeader ("Content-length", params.length);
                ajaxRequest.setRequestHeader ("Connection", "close");

                ajaxRequest.send (params);

                var _this = this;

                ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
                    if (ajaxRequest.readyState === 4) {
                        if (ajaxRequest.status === 200) {
                            _this.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
                        }
                        else {
                            alert ("Error, please try again.");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            window.addEventListener ("load", function () {
                var button = document.getElementsByTagName ("input")[0];
                var id = 1; // Don't know where you get it
                var wishlist = document.getElementById ("wishlist");

                button.addEventListener ("click", function () {
                    wishlist.postAjax ("mode=wishlist&id=" + id, "ajax.php");
                }, false);
            }, false);
        </script>

        <title></title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <input type = "button" value = "Click me man !" />

        <div id = "wishlist"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Multiple clicks:

```
document.body.addEventListener ("click", function (event) {
    var target = event.target;

    if (target.nodeName === "INPUT") {
        if (target.getAttribute ("type") === "button") {
            // Every single button inside your document
        }
    }
}, false);
```

It's the most I can do now, the rest is up to you.

Comment: looks good, but how would i set it up to handle multiple functions for different onclick events?

Comment: @caio i've got it to work upon adding an item to my wishlist, but removing it causes the wishlist to disappear completely, and the wish entry is not removed from the database. But I get no error in Firebug. Original Post updated with new code...

Comment: If you want me to solve your problem your code is going to be completely changed, maybe you won't understand, ok ?

Comment: @caio okay. can you post an example of how you would handle multiple onclick events?

Comment: @caio your edits would work if all the onclick events were on buttons, but some are links and others buttons, and they all do different things. so assigning one action to all buttons or all links would not work.